# Limiting iterations on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm iterating over few user objects and printing their profile avatar url as an image:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <%= image_tag(user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'circle') %>
<% end %>
```

Nice. If I have 100+, I need to limit the image based on the end-user screen size, ie iPad:

```
<% @users.take(8).each do |user| %>
 <%= image_tag(user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'circle') %>
<% end %>
```

I need to know how you pros do it. I have a javascript that [listens for css changes](https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries):

```
// run test on initial page load
checkSize();

// run test on resize of the window
$(window).resize(checkSize);

function checkSize(){
 if ($("#demo").css("display") == "none" ){
  // ajax to get A (users.take(8).each ...)
 } else {
  // ajax to get B (initial view)
 }
});
```

In the place that I call the ajax, I wanted to use render but render cant be used:

```
$("#some-id").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'foo/a') %>"); // or foo/b
```

I have omitted displaying the router and controller. The ajax calls an `.js.erb` file.

This feels like this is a matter of UI/UX decision on how to display those avatar images: should they be shown at all on smaller screens or not. But if I had to, how to limit the iteration on smaller screens?

Comment: when the page first loads, you can get a list of many photo urls. Then in this resize handler you can append or remove them from the DOM.